# Can I change volatile = False to torch.set_grad_enabled(True)??(in Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch

I have old python codes, so I need to change some parts.

```
next_q_values.volatile=False
```

I have this code, and next_q_values is 'torch.Tensor'

when I run this code:

> error occured: "volatile was removed and now has no effect use with
> torch no_grad instead"

After search, I know that `volatile = True` is same as `torch.no_grad()`,
but I want to use `volatile = False`, So I can't use `torch.no_grad()`.

Can I change `volatile = False` to `torch.set_grad_enabled(True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have:

```
next_q_values.volatile = False
```

You can change it to:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    next_q_values
    ...
    # You do something with next_q_values here
```

Every operation on `next_q_values` should be within the scope of context manager.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer! At https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/volatile-now-has-no-effect-use-with-torch-no-grad-instead/26656, volatile = True is changed to torch.no_grad()
But my code is volatile = False, so I think I cannot use torch.no_grad()

Comment: @PeterKim In this case just delete `next_q_values.volatile = False` and you're good to go.